# Telethon events.NewMessage from specific channel

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I would like to get the New Messages from a specific channel.
I have tried the following until now:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 242...
api_hash = '8a06ca620417c9964a058e0dc...'
bot_token = '1474729480:AAEhUPmVX_m...'
channelId = '-36744...'

client = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(channelId))
async def main(event):
     me = client.get_me()
     print(me.stringify())
     print(event.stringify())
        

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Unfortunately, it did not work.
Does anyone know why? Did I miss something?
Greetings

Comment: IDs are integers, not strings. You should remove the quotes from your `channelId` value. Also, `-` indicates it's a small group chat, not a channel. After that's fixed, make sure you enable `logging` to not miss out on errors. The documentation explains how.

Comment: Thank you Lonami, it works fine after fix the value of channelId.

Answer (score 7):

Please use this:

`chats = [channelId]`

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 242...
api_hash = '8a06ca620417c9964a058e0dc...'
bot_token = '1474729480:AAEhUPmVX_m...'
channelId = '-36744...'

client = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = [channelId]))
async def main(event):
     me = client.get_me()
     print(me.stringify())
     print(event.stringify())
    

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you, there is a need to make sure the value of the `chats` argument is specifically a list and not just an Iterable.